# Prepoulating Components With Data In Android Activity onCreate without Getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, oncreate

I have a FragmentActivity with a ViewPager. Inside that ViewPager are a total of 3 different views.

The user selects a row containing information. Once selected, the FragmentActivity shall load and present the data in the views within the ViewPager.

I want the data to be preloaded, so when the activity finally appears, everything is in the correct widget. I am choosing to do this in the onCreate method of the FragmentActivity. However, when I try to access any of the widgets on the views in the ViewPager, I get a NullPointerException.

I do not know how to get around this.

As Per Request:

This block of code, handles calls the FragmentActivity - the "co" is a serialized object containing the information that will be displayed.

```
    TimesheetEdit ts = new TimesheetEdit();     
    Intent result = new Intent(this, ts.getClass());
    result.putExtra("ClientObject", this.co);

    if (v != null) {
        result.putExtra("key", v.getId());
    }
    startActivityForResult(
            result,
            viewType == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.TIMESHEET) ? getResources()
                    .getInteger(R.integer.TIMESHEET) : getResources()
                    .getInteger(R.integer.EXPENSES));
```

The next set of code is the onCreate method of the Fragmentactivity. The Log.i at the end is just for testing purposes, but that is also where my NullPointerException occurs. I assume because for some reason, the View has not been obtained properly from the ViewPager.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timesheetdb_displays_timesheet_edit);
    Log.i("info", "in timesheet edit onCreate");
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Requires API 11 or
    // higher

    this.co = (ClientObject) getIntent().getExtras().get("ClientObject");
    if (getIntent().getExtras().get("key") != null) {
        this.key = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get("key");
        this.co.setRowKey(this.key);
    } else {
        key = 0;
    }

    this.vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.timePager);
    this.vp.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    this.vp.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter());
    this.vp.setCurrentItem(0);

    View v = vp.getChildAt(0);
    Log.i("info", String.format("View id in Hex is: %X", v.getId()));

    //initComponents();
}
```

And finally, the LogCat corresponding to this error is:

```
    11-27 13:21:57.857: W/dalvikvm(710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{timesheetdb.Login/timesheetdb.Displays.TimesheetEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at timesheetdb.Displays.TimesheetEdit.onCreate(TimesheetEdit.java:73)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    11-27 13:21:57.917: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: We probably won't know how to get around this either without more information... post the relevant code and your LogCat errors.

Comment: Is vp.getChildCount() zero?

Comment: Yes vp.getChildCount() is zero. Which is very weird. If I were to comment out the last 2 lines in onCreate, then the Activity loads and the views in the ViewPager show up.